# How to recover Task Tracker and Job Tracker in hadoop?

Tags: linux, hadoop

I had installed hadoop on a single node. And the OS I am using is Ubuntu. I had created a hduser for 1st very successfully. When I removed the existing hduser and created a new hduser in the same system, I am unable to get the task-tracker and job-tracker.

$jps

3750 DataNode

5328 Jps

3978 SecondaryNameNode

3529 NameNode

5156 TaskTracker

Now, my problem is here I am unable to find the Job Tracker. And when I tried using the localhost port numbers, the Task tracker and Job Tracker are not working. What is the reason? How can I recover them?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps may helpful:

1. Look into the log of your JobTracker and TaskTracker. It is usually in your `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/` directory for more details. Or  you can paste the log here, so that other guys can help you find out. Your current description have little information
2. use `netstat` to show if any java process have bind the port you have tried to use.